# How to type Ampersand with Key '7' Broken using Keyboard?

Tags: keyboard

If this question doesn't suit here, request me , I will take it off.

My keyboard's 7 key got damaged and I can't type ampersand without struggling. I am into C programming and can't buy a keyboard right now. Is there any way I can map it somewhere? I am using Ubuntu OS.

Comment: Yeah this isn't really on-topic. Buy a new keyboard, use an on-screen keyboard, copy-paste the symbol you need

Comment: Flagged it myself. No option to delete question in Andriod App.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use xev command to find the keycode of the key you want to use instead of ampersand and run the following command

```
xmodmap -e "keycode xxx = ampersand"
```

Where xxx is the keycode you found.